# .htaccess - Subdomains to folders = subfolders 404

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, directory, virtualhost, subdirectory

Sorry if the title is confusing.

I have set up a *virtual host* on my local machine. I've set `http://dev` to map to my `/htdocs/dev` folder. With some help from *dnsmasq* and *.htaccess*, I've set it up so that it maps subdomains of `.dev` to folders inside `/htdocs/dev`. And it all works perfect when I try to access, for example, `http://dev/file1.html` or `http://folder.dev/file2.html`. The problem occurs with accessing subfolders. I get a `404 Object not found` if I try to access `http://folder.dev/subfolder/` or `http://folder.dev/subfolder/file3.html`.

I guess it can be solved with .htaccess, but I failed to do it although I tried. Here's how my `/htdocs/dev/.htaccess` looks like:

```
# Default index file
  DirectoryIndex index.php

# Interpret .html files as .php scripts
  AddHandler php5-script .php .html

# Redirect subdomains to their respective folders
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dev$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.dev$ [NC]
    RewriteRule !^([a-z0-9-]+)($|/) /%2%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

I should mention that, if I try to access `http://dev/folder/subfolder/file3.html`, there are no problems.

How can I set addresses such as `http://folder.dev/subfolder/` point to `/htdocs/dev/folder/subfolder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thanks goes to @JonLin for giving me a hint about this.

I've managed to solve this with this .htaccess file:

```
# Ordered list of index files, if none exist, show directory listing
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

# Interpret .html files as .php scripts
  AddHandler php5-script .php .html

# Redirect subdirectories to their respective folders
  RewriteEngine on
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dev$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.dev(.*)?$ [NC]
  RewriteRule !^%2\.dev%3?/$ http://dev/%2%{REQUEST_URI}/ [P]
```

What Rewrite part of this does is it takes a URL in form of http://folder.dev/subfolder and points it to /dev/folder/subfolder while preserving the URL. It works with or without www.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your rules to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dev$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.dev$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ /%2%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

Comment: Hi @JonLin thanks for your reply. Do I need to leave or delete these two lines: `RewriteEngine on` and `RewriteBase /`

Comment: So @jon , I've deleted the last three rows in my .htaccess and added your lines. Unfortunately, it's not working. `http://folder.dev` is getting a `500 Internal Server Error` plus `Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`